# We have @login_required, wheres @admin_required

Tags: python, django

I have a method that I'd like to only execute if an admin is logged in.

How do I decorate this method such that only admins can use it?

How do groups work in Django how does `@login_required` handle groups if at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to implement this:

1) Use [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

2) Check the user inside your view:

```
def my_view(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
         return HttpResponse(status=403)  # HTTP 403 Forbidden
    ...
```

Comment: Very nice, will be using this a whole lot!